# Symfony2 what is the best way to make this kind of form

Tags: forms, symfony

i am making a shopping website and i got a probleme with some form. it's about the size part. I am gonna show some screenshots it's gonna be easier to understand :

[image: different choice of size]

what type of field is this kind of form ?

and then i would like the get this to show a list for client

[image]

i dont ask you to do the job for me but if you had some stuff (like a tutorial or some documentation about this kind of form) or some cluee i would really appriciate

Thx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think you are looking for Symfony's [Form Types Reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types.html).

In this case, you are probably talking about a [choice](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html) field. A choice field can be rendered as a set of checkboxes / radio buttons (as in the first image), or as a `<select>` element (dropdown list), as in the second image, depending on wether the [`expanded` option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#expanded) is set to true or false.

Radio buttons:

```
$builder->add('size', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => array('s' => 'S', 'm' => 'M', 'l' => 'L', 'xl' => 'XL'),
    'expanded' => true,
));
```

Dropdown list:

```
$builder->add('size', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => array('s' => 'S', 'm' => 'M', 'l' => 'L', 'xl' => 'XL'),
    'expanded' => false,
));
```

The default value of `expanded` is false, so if you don't specify it, the field will be rendered as a dropdown list.

If you have all available sizes stored in a table in your database, you might want to look at the [entity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) field type as well. The entity type basically extends the choice type, but retrieves the available choices from the database:

```
$builder->add('size', 'choice', array(
    'class' => 'MyWebshopBundle:Size',
    'property' => 'name',
    'expanded' => false,
));
```

This will fetch all `Size` entities from the database, and uses their `name` property in the dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

It's a choice type field

```
  $form = $this->createFormBuilder($data)
            ->add('size', 'choice',
                array('choices' => array(
                    1   => 'X',
                    2 => 'XL',
                  ...
                ),
                    'data' =>'selectionnez la taille'
                ))  
            ->getForm();
```

The option multiple can switch between radio button (false) and checkboxes ( true)
If you prefer a list like this you have to set the expanded attribute to false, true gives checkboxes or radios.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html

Comment: ty for your answer ! (sry i can't upvote i dont have 15 but i would if i could ;) )